# Object parameter is nil, can't determine why

Tags: delphi, object, parameters, delphi-10-seattle

I figure this should be pretty straight forward, but I have no idea why this is not working.

I've taken over legacy code and some of the objects used in a dll are, well, becoming unmanageable.  Several objects have the same procedure

```
SetPropertyValue(propName,propValue:string);
```

Now, these methods are basically giant `if..else` statements that check the `propName` and assign the `propValue` if it matches the objects property:

```
if propName='name' then
  name:=propValue
else if propName='address' then
  address:=propValue
```

And so on.

Each time an object gets a new property (or a property type changes and therefore the value parameter being passed in needs to be cast differently), this method needs updating - obviously a chore that shouldn't need to be.

I've opted to write a global method to set an objects property that is dynamic and should need minimal maintenance.

Here is an short example of what I am doing so far.  There are two units, Obj and Main - where Main is a VCL form with 2 edit boxes and a button, I am using button click to trigger the SetPropertyValue:

Obj

```
unit Obj;

interface

uses
  RTTI;

{$RTTI INHERIT}
type TmyObj = class(TObject)
  Name:String;
  Address:String;
  City:String;

  procedure SetPropertyValue(sPropName, sPropValue:String);
end;


procedure SetObjProperty(AObject : TObject; propName, propValue:String);

implementation

procedure SetObjProperty(AObject : TObject; propName, propValue:String);
var
  context:TRttiContext;
  rt: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
begin

  if not Assigned(AObject) then
    exit;

  context:=RTTIContext.Create;
  rt:=Context.GetType(AObject.ClassType);

  for prop in rt.GetProperties do
  begin

  //do some stuff 

  end;

  Context.Free;

end;

{ TmyObj }

procedure TmyObj.SetPropertyValue(sPropName, sPropValue: String);
begin
  SetObjProperty(self, sPropName, sPropValue);
end;

end.
```

Main

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtPropName: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    edtPropValue: TEdit;
    btnGo: TButton;
    procedure btnGoClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Obj;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnGoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  myObj:TMyObj;
begin

  myObj:=TMyObj.Create;
  myObj.SetPropertyValue(edtPropName.Text, edtPropValue.Text);

end;

end.
```

Rather than change the `obj.SetPropertyValue` (because I would have to change it over and over again in code), I just referenced the new procedure.

Unfortunately, no matter how I try to reference the object in `Obj.SetPropertyValyue` it is always empty in `SetObjectProperty` - so the `rt` is always empty and the loop doesn't do anything.

I know when passing an object, we are just passing a pointer, so even though I change the argument type to `CONST`, I still get the same empty/nil value when I enter the new procedure.

Any thoughts on what I have down wrong?  I've even tried referencing `SetObjProperty` outside of the unit, so:

```
thisObj:=TMyObj.Create;
SetObjProperty(thisObj,sThisName, sThisValue);
```

But I still end up with the same `nil` obj in my new method.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do not `Free` the objects obtained from `TRttiContext`, they are owned by an internal cache and will be freed automatically. You should also declare a `TRttiContext` variable and let it go out of scope when the function exits, to make sure the cache stays valid during the function. Calling `TRttiContext.Create` is optional.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau - one less thing to worry about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any thoughts on what I have down wrong?

You are looping through properties using [RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.GetProperties), but your `TMyObj` has no declared [properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties).

Here is a small example how to do:

```
program Project62;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  RTTI;

{$RTTI INHERIT}
type 
  TmyObj = class(TObject)
  private
    FName:String;
    FAddress:String;
    FCity:String;
  public
    property Name: String read FName write FName;
    property Address: String read FAddress write FAddress;

    procedure SetPropertyValue(sPropName, sPropValue:String);
  end;

procedure SetObjProperty(AObject : TObject; propName, propValue:String);
var
  context:TRttiContext;
  rt: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  if not Assigned(AObject) then begin
    WriteLn('Not assigned');
    exit;
  end;
  rt:= Context.GetType(AObject.ClassType);
  for prop in rt.GetProperties do
  begin
    if (propName = 'Name') then
      prop.SetValue(AObject,propValue)
    else if (propName = 'Address') then
      prop.SetValue(AObject,propValue);
  end;
end;

procedure TmyObj.SetPropertyValue(sPropName, sPropValue: String);
begin
  SetObjProperty(self, sPropName, sPropValue);
end;

var
  myObj:TMyObj;
begin

  myObj:= TMyObj.Create;
  myObj.SetPropertyValue('Name', '1');
  WriteLn(myObj.Name);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: It's been a long week, so I'll scratch this one up to being tired.   You are 100% correct, the fact that these are not properties means that, aside from re-declaring them as properties, I should have been using RTTIFields!!!  Once you pointed that out, I saw my mistake and had it fixed in an instant.

A good way to finish on a Friday - thanks for the assist!